# Is it possible to get superclass and subclass attributes on the subclass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have an `LuxuryAutomobile` that inherits from `Automobile`.  I want to get all the normal attributes like `:num_doors` but I also want to get the special attributes like `:num_screens`.

```
create_table :automobiles do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.integer :num_wheels
  t.integer :num_doors
  t.string :color
end

create_table :luxury_automobiles do |t|
  t.boolean :leather_seats
  t.integer :num_screens
  t.string :custom_monogram
end
```

So I inherit everything from Automobile:

```
class LuxuryAutomobile < Automobile


end
```

I can get the number of wheels, but I can't set or get the number of screens.

```
porsche = LuxuryAutomobile(num_wheels: 4, user: u)
porsche.num_wheels # => 4
porsche.num_screens #(undefined method `num_screens=' for #<LuxuryAutomobile:0x00007fa1e7cf17b0>)
```

I'd basically like to keep the functionality of the subclass (all its additional attributes) but in the event that something is not implemented, it should get it from the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

first, you could check the database `table` that a `ActiveRecord` point to

```rb
class LuxuryAutomobile < Automobile
end
LuxuryAutomobile.table_name # automobiles
```

so you have to set explicitly the db table name

```rb
class LuxuryAutomobile < Automobile
 self.table_name = "luxury_automobiles"
end
LuxuryAutomobile.table_name # luxury_automobiles
```

now the class `LuxuryAutomobile` point to the table `luxury_automobiles` and also inherit the `logic` of the parent class `Automobile` BUT NOT the data from the table `automobiles`.

```rb
class Automobile < ApplicationRecord
 def decorator
   "decorator"
 end 
end

class LuxuryAutomobile < Automobile
 self.table_name = "luxury_automobiles"
end

LuxuryAutomobile.first.decorator # "decorator"
LuxuryAutomobile.first.num_wheels # nil
```

so you have to either duplicate the data table or delegate get/set db attributes to `Automobile`

```rb
# migration
class AddAutomobileRefToLuxuryAutomobiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
 def change
   add_reference :luxury_automobiles, :automobile, foreign_key: true
 end
end

class LuxuryAutomobile < Automobile
 self.table_name = "luxury_automobiles"
 belongs_to :automobile
 delegate :num_wheels, to: :automobile
end

LuxuryAutomobile.first.decorator # "decorator"
LuxuryAutomobile.first.num_wheels # 4
```

now you also could do like this

```rb
class LuxuryAutomobile < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :automobile
 delegate_missing_to :automobile
end

LuxuryAutomobile.table_name # "luxury_automobiles"
LuxuryAutomobile.first.decorator # "decorator"
LuxuryAutomobile.first.num_wheels # 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not in the exact way you are describing.

You would need to use STI in order to accomplish this. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

---

The other option is using [delegate](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/Module/delegate) in your model.

```
delegate :user, :num_wheels, :num_doors, :color, to: :parent_car # Replace parent car with whatever the relationship actually is.
```

But that wont allow you to do:

```
porsche = LuxuryAutomobile(num_wheels: 4, user: u)
```

You would have to create the records separately or use `accepts_nested_attributes`

I would use STI for what you are doing. I'm not sure if the base table *has* to be abstract or not. It's not something I've ever done.